# jOOQ SELECT FOR UPDATE lock never released

Tags: java, sql, jooq, pessimistic-locking

I'm using jOOQ to do a SELECT FOR UPDATE on a row to synchronize a subsequent MERGE operation. However when the MERGE is completed, the lock held by the FOR UPDATE is never released. My DataSourceConnectionProvider has been fed a ComboPooledDataSource (connection pool).

I'm not doing anything explicit with the connention. All I do is:

1) get DSL context
2) Execute SELECT FOR UPDATE .. NO WAIT
3) Execute MERGE
4) Let the thread return

Any idea on how to ensure that the lock is released?

Comment: It will help showing some of the relevant code (most importanly how the pool manages transactions). Also, what is the database?